# Functor compile time error

Tags: c++, c++11, functor, standard-library

My code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#include "boost\numeric\ublas\matrix.hpp"

typedef boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<float> matrix;


class FillMat{  
public:
    FillMat(float valIn) : val(valIn){}
    float operator()(float in) {
        val = in + 1;
        return val;
    }
private:
    float val;
};

typedef boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<float> matrix;
int main(){
    matrix m1(10, 20);
    float init = 22.2;
    FillMat myFiller(init);

    generate(m1.begin2(), m1.begin2() + m1.size1()*m1.size2(), myFiller);


    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the code, I get the following compile time error.

```
Error   3   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
```

Can someone please tell me why?

P.S. I added the headers. I am using Boost matrix for 2D array.

Comment: Can't you present an MCVE? We don't even know what line that error was generated on...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll try with vector. Will that do?

Comment: Will that do for _what_? You haven't told us what you're trying to do...

Comment: Boost usage is not what's wrong with your test case, it's the lack of headers etc. A good test case would be one that allows us to copy-paste and compile as is, without having to guess what headers we might need to include.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am trying to fill the contents of my container such with incrementing values

Comment: @Praetorian I added the headers

Comment: The error tells everything already. The functor you pass must have no argument but your functor has 1 float argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the clarification in the comment ("I am trying to fill the contents of my container such with incrementing values") what you really want is `std::iota`. I haven't quite gotten straight what you're trying to do with your `matrix`, and how you want the values to increment (row-wise or column-wise), so I'll give a demo with a normal vector, and let you figure out how to apply it in your actual situation:

```
std::vector<int> v(10);

std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 22.2);

for (auto i : v)
    std::cout << i << " ";
```

Should produce: `22.2 23.2 24.2 25.2 26.2 27.2 28.2 29.2 30.2 31.2`

Answer (score 2):

The signature of the functor you pass to `std::generate` must take zero arguments.

This is stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate).

Unfortunately, you didn't tell us what you are trying to do, so I can't suggest a fix for you.

Answer (score 2):

A possible fix would be to change:

```
  float operator()(float in) {
        val = in + 1;
        return val;
    }
```

into:

```
   float operator()( void ) {
        float rv = val;
        val = val + 1.0;
        return rv;
    }
```

If that does what you *want*, that is the question ...

Answer (score 2):

The function you're looking for is `std::transform`:

```
std::transform(m1.begin2(),
               m1.begin2() + m1.size1() * m1.size2(),
               m1.begin2(),
               myFiller);
```